# Dispose and reload textures when I show interstitial ads?

Tags: android, libgdx, dispose, interstitial, openglcontext

My question is - do I really need to dispose and reload my textures when I show interstitial ads?

The situation is - when I am showing Interstitial ads (e.g. from Admob) in my game, my pause and resume methods are called (the ad is shown as a new Android activity inside my app, which is eventually closed). Correspondingly I dispose and reload my textures. This seems like an overkill to do each time an ad is shown. Is there a way to ensure my GL context is not lost?

Is it really lost without me leaving my application or this is just an insurance in case the ad activity really suspends my application when for example the ad gets clicked? Or is the interstitial ad actually shown in a new process?...

Comment: You use AssetManager? In my games I load the textures on start the game, and dispose on finish.

Comment: As far as I know if you click the ad it open in a new window, i.e ur app is still running. As Douglas said, if you use assetManager there is no reason to dispose anything just to show an ad.